# Changing one object's member in a LinkedList changes all objects

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, arduino, linked-list

I'm sorry I'm quite new to C++ and i'm coding an Arduino sketch.

I wanted to implement a command-oriented approach, where I have a queue of commands, a parent virtual/abstract class Command, and every actual command inherits from this class.

In order to implement this queue, I'm using a LinkedList library that i got from the Arduino's library manager (some sort of "library store"). So that I have:

```
LinkedList<Command*> queue = new LinkedList<Command*>();
```

I added the * because otherwise it won't compile.

The thing is that I'm pushing commands to the queue using the "new" operator. If I'm working with just one object in the list, it works properly, but the intention is to have more than one command in the queue, the problem is that if I change an instance's member, it'll change all the other instances in the queue as well, as if all of them were pointing to the same instance. Of course, the variables are not declared as static.

I suspect it's because of  the * in the list initialization, but to be honest, I haven't yet completely understood C++ pointers, and this is just a wild guess.

Update #1: Answering molbdnilo request. Here's the minimal reproducible example (You'll need the LinkedListLib library created by Luis Llamas, can be obtained from the Arduino Library Manager):

```
#include <LinkedListLib.h>

// Definiciones
class Command {

  private:
  String state = "NOT_EXEC"; // Estados: NOT_EXEC, NOT_FINISHED, FINISHED
  
  public: 
  virtual void init() = 0; // Función de inicialización de comando
  virtual void exec() = 0; // Función de ejecución del comando
  virtual void finish() = 0; // Función de finalizado del comando
  void setStatus(String s){ state = s;};
  virtual ~Command(){};
  String getStatus(){
    return state;
  } // Entrega el estado del comando
  
  
};

class Parpadear : public Command{
  private: 
  long t;
  int c = 0;
  int stat;
  int mil;
  int rep;
  
  public:
  Parpadear(int x, int y){
  mil = x;
  rep = y;
  }
  void init() override{
    t = millis();
    stat = HIGH;
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, stat);
  }

  void exec() override{
   if (millis() - t > mil){
    stat = stat == HIGH ? LOW : HIGH; 
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, stat);
    t = millis();
    c++;
    }

    if(c == rep){
      setStatus("FINISHED");
    }
  }

  void finish() override{

  }

  Parpadear::~Parpadear(){
    
  }
};

// Estados: 1 = init, 2 = exec, 3 = main
const int INIT = 1; // Initialization state
const int EXEC = 2; // Command execution state
const int MAIN = 3; // Main loop code state
int state = INIT;
long init_time;
LinkedList<Command*> queue = LinkedList<Command*>();
String commandResult;


void setup() {
  // Inicialización de Arduino
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT); // Configura LED en tabla  
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  // Máquina de estados para control global de la estructura orientada a comandos
  switch(state){
    case INIT:
      // Inicialización de la máquina de estados
      init_time = millis(); // Obtener el tiempo en el que la máquina de estados se empezó a ejecutar por primera vez.
      state = EXEC; // Realizar transición a ejecución de comandos.
      queue.InsertHead(new Parpadear(2000, 4));
      queue.InsertTail(new Parpadear(300, 50));
      break;
    case EXEC:
      // Ejecución de comandos en cola
      if(queue.GetSize() > 0){
        if(queue.GetHead()->getStatus() == "NOT_EXEC"){
          queue.GetHead()->init();
          queue.GetHead()->setStatus("NOT_FINISHED");
        }
        queue.GetHead()->exec(); // Ejecuta primer comando en la cola
        if(queue.GetHead()->getStatus() == "FINISHED"){
          //Serial.println(queue.GetHead()->getStatus());
          queue.GetHead()->finish();
          queue.RemoveAt(0); // Quitar el primer comando de la lista
        }
      }
      break;
    case MAIN:
      break;
  }

}
```

Update #2: Regarding Botje's question:

How did I determine that is changing both instances ?

(please refer to the switch case EXEC, for code reference)

All Commands that inherit from the parent Command class (In this case, only the class Parpadear is implemented), have a String variable called "state" that stores the state of the command, so every time a command is queued, it is only when it finishes its execution, that this "state" variable changes its value to "FINISHED" (otherwise it'll be "NOT_FINISHED"), this triggers the queue to remove the command from the list.

Using the Serial Monitor tool from Arduino, I was able to see that after queuing 2 commands, the first one will execute accordingly, but once the first gets removed, the second one gets immediatly removed as well. I used Serial.println to print the "state" variable for every command, and all of them result in "FINISHED" when the other one shouldn't.

Also printed the variable "c" which is nothing but a counter, and in both instances it equals the same value (4), being that in the second instance "c" hasn't even been manipulated yet.

Comment: Please read about the [mcve], and then create one.

Comment: How did you determine that all other instances in the queue change as well? Where is the code that suffers from that?

Comment: Thank's y'all for answering, I updated the question to address your concerns. Thank you all again !

Answer (score 0):

Changing to another Library solved the issue. Ironically, developed by the same author.

In this case i'm using a List instead of a LinkedList, is there any difference ?

Probably the other library is outdated, or handles pointers in an obscure way, but just for the record, the library I'm using right now is "ListLib", can also be obtained from the Arduino Library Manager